# calling a java program from CentOS 7 terminal

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, terminal, centos

I am using [the code from this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) to test the JDBC connection.  I changed the name of the class to TestJDBC and I altered the database name and query, but otherwise it is identical.  When I run the class as a Java application from within eclipse on my devbox, the program runs properly.  However, when I copy the file to `/home/username/` on a remote `CentOS 7` server, typing `java TestJDBC.java` into the terminal produces the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TestJDBC.java
```

I also the same error when I try `java TestJDBC` and when I upload the `.class` file in addition to just the `.java` file.  **What else do I need to do in order to call the Java class from the `CentOS 7` terminal?**

Note that `javac TestJDBC.java` results in `-bash: javac: command not found`.  And I did try `java somepackage.TestJDBC` with same results of `Error: Could not find or load main class TestJDBC.java` as above.

**ANSWER NOTE:**  **The answer required getting the development version of openJDK using yum.  The PATH variable was not part of the solution.**  However, I am marking the answer below as accepted because the user who submitted it contributed substantially to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run it after compiling it

```
javac TestJDBC.java
java TestJDBC
```

Note that you do not need to add `.class` when running it from the commandline.

If this still does not work, please paste your code.

**EDIT after request**

So you've now stated that you're missing `javac` from your PATH. I'll show you how to add it:

```
$> export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/jdk.1.8.0_20
$> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Verify by running

```
javac -version
```

It should print something like

```
javac 1.8.0_20
```

Comment: @CodeMed Your question was lacking way too much information to able me to post a better answer. You state that it has a main method and it won't run... That's pretty much it.
However, I see your edit to the question and I'd like to ask you to append the jdk/JAVA_HOME to your PATH variable. That way you can call `javac` directly. You need to compile your class before running it.

Comment: @CodeMed if you are not sure about the path to java, try `$> which java` or `$> whereis java`

Comment: @CodeMed It should be the same commands... Export the JAVA_HOME variable first, pointing at /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
Then append the variable to your path like i described.
I haven't worked with openjdk in a very long time, so I'm not 100% familiar with it. I'd say get the Oracle version

Comment: @CodeMed  What `which java` shows? Also you can try `find /usr/lib/jvm -name javac`, should show paths to all javac files.

Comment: @CodeMed I agree with Robin Jonsson, why don't get Oracle version?

Comment: @CodeMed do `find /bin/java -name javac` Obviously it will show nothing as you have installed jre, not jdk. So you need either change JAVA_HOME completely to what you need as Robin showed or add path to javac. You can add path to javac by locating it in your openjdk or Oracle jdk directory (I gave command `find ...` before) and doing `export PATH=$PATH:path/to/jdkdirectory/bin`. This command will append new directory to the PATH variably allowing you to call the program without writing the whole path to it. You can do this for any program, BTW. Regarding javac - that's all I can do.